# SettingWithCopyWarning when using 'apply' in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, apply

I have a very big pandas data frame, on which I need to run a small routine. I tried to do this through iteration, but this takes an extremely long time. I thought I found a solution by doing this by using the 'apply' function, but I get the following error message:

> /var/folders/cx/xcst49yn5fv9tx_rdvzvmtw80000gn/T/ipykernel_79875/394695383.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> ehs['tas50'] = ehs.apply(lambda row: pms.commb.tas50(row.rawmsg), axis = 1)

I tried to use the apply function to avoid iteration:

```
    ehs['tas50'] = ehs.apply(lambda row: pms.commb.tas50(row.rawmsg), axis = 1)
```

The warning mentions: "Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" , but how can this be done without going through the whole data frame row by row?

I did try the following iteration, which doesn't take too long:

```
    for i in range(len(ehs)):
        msg = ehs.loc[i,'rawmsg']
        ehs.at[i,'tas50'] = pms.commb.tas50(msg)
```

but I get the same warning, even though I clearly use the .loc and .at function.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `apply` is slower then a classical python loop

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: It's a warning because you might get unexpected results in some cases, if your result is what you expect, be mindful but don't worry too much**

What you're getting is a warning, not an error. And it warns you that you're replacing the values in the original dataframe. Why does it warn you? Because you might not want to do that. If you look into the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) you get in the warning, it says:

> care must be taken to avoid what is called `chained indexing`

chained indexing is using [][], you have an example in code in the link. After the example, they explain why `.loc()` is preferred to chained indexing and how each method works. Again, from the link you shared:

> dfmi['one'] selects the first level of the columns and returns a DataFrame that is singly-indexed. Then another Python operation dfmi_with_one['second'] selects the series indexed by 'second'. This is indicated by the variable dfmi_with_one because pandas sees these operations as separate events. e.g. separate calls to **getitem**, so it has to treat them as linear operations, they happen one after another.

Contrast this to df.loc[:,('one','second')] which passes a nested tuple of (slice(None),('one','second')) to a single call to **getitem**. This allows pandas to deal with this as a single entity. Furthermore this order of operations can be significantly faster, and allows one to index both axes if so desired.

If you keep reading, you end up at [this title](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) where it explains the warning and the problems that might arise:

> The problem in the previous section is just a performance issue. What’s up with the SettingWithCopy warning? We don’t usually throw warnings around when you do something that might cost a few extra milliseconds!

> But it turns out that assigning to the product of chained indexing has inherently unpredictable results.

In the end, check whether you're getting your desired result and the link, if you're getting what you want and you're confident it's not going to change, you can ignore that warning. It's just telling you to be careful when setting values in slices of dataframes.

If the warnings are bothering you, doing

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

where you change the DeprecationWarning for the type of warning you're getting should mute them **(careful, as this will silence all warnings of that type)**

Comment: Thank you, @David. I did read up on it, but I wasn't aware of how to avoid the warning. I managed to avoid the warning by using a deep copy to work on.

Comment: You can silence it if it bothers you by doing `import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=WarningCategory)`